# Simplification of permutation $(1 2 3 4) (4 5 6 7)$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

Basic problem,

I'm confused on how to simplify this permutation into disjoint permutations?

$(1 2 3 4) (4 5 6 7)$

I am struggling between $(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)$ and $(1 2 3 5 6 7 4)$?

Thanks!

Comment: Either answer is possible depending on whether you compose permutations from left to right or from right to left. Right to left is more usual i.e. first $(4567)$ and then $(1234)$, which gives  $(1234567)$.

Comment: Wouldn't you usually start from the smallest number $1$ in this case, so always left to right?

Comment: As I said, right to left is more usual, so I would recommend that you stick to that if you are confused.

Comment: @DerekHolt is right - you will need to check the convention being used in the source of the question: it is simply a matter of convention which you do first.

Comment: Alternatively, if it is unclear, use the more common convention, and state that this is the one you have used.

Comment: @MarkBennet I'm surprised there are two conventions! Would the change in convention result in different answers, if say, calculating conjugacy classes in $S_n$? I'm guessing not?

Comment: Each convention is internally consistent and gives the correct results for any question about the symmetric groups. Mixing conventions leads to inconsistencies and errors.

Comment: The conventions do not affect conjugacy classes. I am afraid that you have get used to the fact that different books and different mathematicians use different conventions and notation. It's a fact of life! For example, is $0$ a natural number? Or even, does "positive" mean greater than $0$ or greater than equal to $0$? Does ${\mathbb Z}_p$ denote the integers modulo $p$ or the $p$-adic integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decompose these two permutations into product of transpositions, you will get:
$$(1234)(4567)=(12)(23)(34)(45)(56)(67),$$
so from here you can notice that this is the decomposition into transpositions of the permutation $(1234567)$, so we conclude that
$$(1234)(4567)=(1234567).$$

If you want to calculate it directly, you have to take a look to where does each number go (doing the permutations from right to left, so the first arrow points to the number after the right permutation and the second points to the number after the left permutation):
$$ 1 \to 1\to 2$$
$$ 2 \to 2\to 3$$
$$ 3 \to 3\to 4$$
$$ 4 \to 5\to 5$$
$$ 5 \to 6\to 6$$
$$ 6 \to 7\to 7$$
$$ 7 \to 4\to 1$$
And, as you see, this gives us the same permutation result: $(1234567)$.

Comment: Would, for example, $(2 6 5)(1 4 7 3 5)$ simplify to $(1 4 7 3 5 2 6)$?

Comment: I really can't see how it helps to decompose the permutations into transpositions. It is much quicker and easier to calculate it directly. In any case, it appears that the OP's confusion is resulting from uncertainty about the convention for composing permutations.

Comment: With the right to left convention, $(265)(14735) = (1473265)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt usually it does not help, but in this case it's seen so easily after decomposing it into transpositions, so in my opinion it's the easiest way to understand it in this case. You're right when you say that calculating it directly is always better, but in this particular case this works very well.

Comment: @DerekHolt I edited it to include both ways of solving it, I hope it's a better answer now. Thanks for your previous comment.